# DB logging using Fluent Interface

Tags: enterprise-library-5

I'm using Enterprise library 5.0. Using fluent interface I was able to configure Trace Listners for File based and Event based logging. Is there any way I can configure it for Database listner. My idea is not to use any external configuration file specific to Logging configuration.

I used the following, I'm able to log in a flatFile, Event viewer. When I try to log using DBListner, I'm not getting any error message but the message also is not getting logged. Can anyone shed some light?

```
.SendTo.RollingFile("Flat File Trace Listener")
        .ToFile("Trace.log")
        .WithHeader("----------------------")
        .FormatWith(new FormatterBuilder()
        .TextFormatterNamed("Text Formatter")
        .UsingTemplate("Timestamp: {timestamp}{newline}Message: {message}{newline}Category: {category}{newline}Priority: {priority}{newline}EventId: {eventid}{newline}Severity: {severity}{newline}Title:{title}{newline}Machine: {machine}{newline}Application Domain: {appDomain}{newline}Process Id: {processId}{newline}Process Name: {processName}{newline}Win32 Thread Id: {win32ThreadId}{newline}Thread Name: {threadName}{newline}Extended Properties: {dictionary({key} - {value}{newline})}"))

        .SendTo.EventLog("Formatted EventLog TraceListener")
        .FormatWithSharedFormatter("Text Formatter")
        .ToLog("Application")
        .LogToCategoryNamed("General").WithOptions.SetAsDefaultCategory()

        .SendTo.Database("Formatted Database TraceListener")
        .UseDatabase("MyDatabase")            
        .FormatWith(new FormatterBuilder().TextFormatterNamed("TextFormat"))
        .WithWriteLogStoredProcedure("WriteLog")
        .WithAddCategoryStoredProcedure ("AddCategory")
        .LogToCategoryNamed("DBLogger").WithOptions.SetAsDefaultCategory();

        builder.ConfigureData()
        .ForDatabaseNamed("MyDatabase")
        .ThatIs.ASqlDatabase()
        .WithConnectionString("Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=Logging;Integrated ecurity=True;")
        .AsDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

The LogToCategoryNamed method has to come first. Something like this:

```
.LogToCategoryNamed("DBLogger")
    .SendTo.Database("Formatted Database TraceListener")
        .UseDatabase("MyDatabase")
        .FormatWith(new FormatterBuilder().TextFormatterNamed("Text Formatter"));
```

Documentation on using the fluent API for logging can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664363%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx#fluent_api_logging).